# Cloud9 autogenerate getters and setters?

Tags: php, getter-setter, cloud9-ide

I'm working with cloud9 learning PHP for a class.  I was wondering, is there a way to autogenerate Getters and Setters based on your class variables?

I know you can do this in Eclipse, but wasn't sure if there was a hotkey or setting for this with Cloud9

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, Cloud9 does not have an interface or hotkey for automatically creating classes or files like this.